# gulp-changed has different behaviours

Tags: html, svg, sprite, gulp

In my website build-process, I use gulp-changed to prevent doing all task if unnecessary. However, sometimes it has different behaviours even if declarations are similar.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

**case 1** : building htlm / php using partials.
*works fine! the task process only the first time, if I run it twice in a row*

```
gulp.task('pages', function () {

    var toBuild = src + config.pages.src_pages; // many php/html files
    var partials = src + config.pages.src_partials; // "to be included"
    var DEST = target;

    return gulp.src([toBuild, "!" + partials])
        .pipe(changed(DEST))
        .pipe(fileinclude({  prefix: '@@', basepath: '@file' }))
        .pipe(size())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(DEST));
});
```

**case 2** : building a SVG sprite from multiple svg files.
*doesn't work! the task runs again if I run it twice in a row*

```
gulp.task('vector', function () {

   var DEST = target + config.assets.images.vector_dest; 
   var configsvg = { // ... config stuff // };

   return gulp.src(src + config.assets.images.vector_src)
        .pipe(changed(DEST))
        .pipe(svgo())
        .pipe(svgSprite(configsvg)).on('error', function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
        .pipe(size())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(DEST));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use gulp-newer module in case of "many to one" file compilation (concatenation etc...)

Thank you to Lim H.
[gulp-newer vs gulp-changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24730215/gulp-newer-vs-gulp-changed)

Answer (score 0):

May I also suggest [gulp-newy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-newy) in which you can manipulate the path and  filename in your own function. Then, just use the function as the callback to the `newy()`. This gives you complete control of the files you would like to compare.

This will allow 1:1 or many to 1 compares.

```
newy(function(projectDir, srcFile, absSrcFile) {
  // do whatever you want to here. 
  // construct your absolute path, change filename suffix, etc. 
  // then return /foo/bar/filename.suffix as the file to compare against
}
```

[image]