# gulp: pass only files changed in pipe

Tags: gulp, gulp-changed, gulp-newer, gulp-replace, gulp-cached

I try to sort through files, substitute text in some and save only changed. In my current code `gulp-changed` does nothing.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const changed = require('gulp-changed');
const replace = require('gulp-replace');

gulp.task('text-replace', function(){

    var before = 'xxx';
    var after = 'yyy';

gulp.src('src/**/*')
    .pipe(replace(before, after))
    .pipe(changed('src'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
});
```

**UPDATE:** I almost solved this myself, but there is a small issue related to `gulp-cached` in my answer down below.

Answer (score 0):

According to [gulp-newer vs gulp-changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24730215/gulp-newer-vs-gulp-changed#answer-29022596) gulp-changed and gulp-newer don't compare stream files with files in directories, they compare 'src' directory files with 'dest' directory files, and according to that decide what to do with stream files. There is another solution:

```
const cache = require('gulp-cached');

gulp.src('src/**/*')
    .pipe(cache('just_cache_name'))
    .pipe(replace(before, after))
    .pipe(cache('just_cache_name'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
});
```

Still, there is a problem - I have `src` directory structure completely recreated in `dest`, no matter if it's with files or empty.