# How can I run a gulp imagemin task only on new and changed files?

Tags: gulp, gulp-imagemin

I tried to add a gulp task like below and run gulp images so that it only runs only on added/changed files However, that seems to not work...Any idea?

```
  gulp.task('images', function (event) {
  switch (event.type)
  {
    case 'added':
    case 'changed':
      gulp.src(event.path)
        return gulp.src(config.images.src)
        .pipe(imagemin({
          optimizationLevel: 5,
          progressive: true,
          svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
          use: [pngcrush()]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.images.dest));
      break;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [gulp-newer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-newer) to only pass newer files.

Insert a pipe before imagemin with the destination folder as parameter.

```
gulp.task('images', function (event) {
  gulp.src(event.path)
    return gulp.src(config.images.src)
    .pipe(newer(config.images.dest))
    .pipe(imagemin({
      optimizationLevel: 5,
      progressive: true,
      svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
      use: [pngcrush()]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.images.dest));
});
```

Comment: Sounds great. However what if the file changes but not exactly a brand new file? Will ths work?

Comment: It uses modified time to determine if the src file is newer than the dest file. So if the file change updates the modified time then yes it'll work.

Comment: I think if you send a path, if any file has changed every file is piped on.

Answer (score 3):

Besides `gulp-newer` as mentioned by @Headwiki, the other popular tool for this is [`gulp-changed`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-changed).

Depending on your exact needs `gulp-newer` or `gulp-changed` might be better… or for your project it might not make a different. For more on that, see the question ["gulp-newer vs gulp-changed?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24730215/gulp-newer-vs-gulp-changed)